# Rails undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

I am having problems building a new Rails app.

When trying to run `@invoice.total` in the view, I get this error:

```
undefined method `*' for nil:NilClass
```

However, running `@invoice.total` works in the console. I have tried using HAML and/or ERB with the same problem.

The code which runs for `@invoice.total` is in the model and is below:

```
def items_total
  items_total = 0
  self.invoice_items.each do |i|
    items_total += i.price * i.quantity
  end
  items_total
end


# instead of copying this code all of the time
def vat_calc
  (1 + self.vat_rate / 100)
end

def discount_calc
  (1 - self.discount / 100)
end

# total times to add vat on top and remove discount
def total
  items_total * discount_calc * vat_calc
end
```

The invoice has vat_rate and discount set to 0 and each of the items (there are 3) have inc_vat as 1.

What's the problem?

Comment: Are you using `select` in a controller action somewhere to limit the fields returned for your invoice items? That can cause the behavior you see where it works fine in a console but fails in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had `@invoice_item = @invoice.invoice_items.new` in the show area of the invoices controller instead of `@invoice_item = InvoiceItem.new` for the Invoice Item creation form.

It *had* been working though :/

**Thanks**!